# How to find whether an application in android is accessing internet?

Tags: android, networking

Can anyone help how to find out whether any installed application in android is accessing internet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will require the internet permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Regards,
 Stéphane